# preg_match to check "if reach" end of string, not "match character at" end of string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I Google and search this site but doesn't find similar question which I think it's a rare question: I write this RegExp

```
#<img .+?/font_image/(.{4})\.gif.*?>#
```

in preg_match() to check this pattern

```
<img src=".../font_image/xxxx.gif" ...>
```

In text but sometimes the '>' is missing due to typo.

How can I modify this RegExp to match either a **>** or **end-of-string** cases (note: Can't use $ since I wouldn't know what is the last character at end of string, I tried `#<img .+?/font_image/(.{4})\.gif.*?>#` but it doesn't work)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `>$` inside a group delimited by `|` . Note that don't use char class for this type of OR operation since `$` inside a char class should loose it's special meaning.

```
<img .+?/font_image/(.{4})\.gif.*?(?:>|$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tG0dJ8/1)

Comment: Thanks! You save my day. :)

Comment: Why add lookahead ?: Can't we just use (>|$)?

Comment: who said `?:` a lookahead? It's a non-capturing group.

Comment: Oh! I misunderstand it. Thanks!

Comment: TIL that my use of `[^$]` for years **is wrong**. Woops. I somehow thought it'd be faster than `.*$`, and my strings didn't contain any `$`s in them... until today! lol